# can someone explain the code execution here

Tags: python, recursion

this is a simple implementation of the euclidian algorithm
but it always returns None
The sample input is A=270 and B = 192 should return 6
I am not neccesarily looking for code just an explaination on why it returns none instead of an integer.
Thanks

Code:

```
def GCD(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        print("B") # for debugging
        return int(b)
    elif b == 0:
        print("A") # for debugging
        return int(a)
    else:
        GCD(int(b), int((a%b))) # recursive function call

print(GCD(int(input("A:")),int(input("B:"))))
```

Output:

```
A:270
B:192
A
None
```

Comment: Hint 1: Imagine if, instead of recursively calling `GCD(int(b), int((a%b)))`, you instead wrote `karls_GCD(int(b), int((a%b)))`, where `karls_GCD` is a GCD algorithm that I wrote and you `import`ed into the code. Do you see why there would be a problem, *even assuming my code is correct*? The recursive call is *not different*. Hint 2: on the lines of code where you wrote `return int(b)` and `return int(a)`, why did you **not** instead just write `int(b) `and `int(a)`? Why would that not work? Again, the recursive call is *not different*; you're still *calling* something.

Comment: I got it, thanks